# How to allow check box to work in SharePoint without being in 'edit in grid view'?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have a tracking sheet that I manage and I would like the ability to make the check box, which represents that a job has been completed, to be able to be checked (Yes/No Check box) without having to enter '*Edit in grid view*'. Is this possible on the back end of SharePoint or through json?

I've looked at the settings in the SharePoint list and the column properties. Quick Edit is activated but it isn't doing what I hoped.

[image: Completed column]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that you want to fill in the checkbox column, but not in the "Edit in grid view".

If you want to edit items in the SharePoint list, you could through "Edit in grid view", "Edit item properties" and flows.

You could edit items by using " Update item" action when a job has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. It is possible to edit the **Yes/No** column in SharePoint list view without using grid view.

You have to apply JSON column formatting for your Yes/No column. Use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "inlineEditField": "[$Completed]",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Completed], 'Yes', 'No')"
}
```

Where `[$Completed]` is the **internal name** of your column.

**Output**: When you click on column cell, it will open column in edit mode:

[image]

**Documentation**:

1. [SharePoint JSON column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [JSON formatting inlineEditField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#inlineeditfield)